# PHP include different directory

Tags: php, html, css, include, relative-path

i have a website which has this structure:

- /ROOT DIRECTORY/

  - Product/

    - products.php
- CSS/

  - style.css
- index.php

so here's the problem: index.php links the style.css with relative path like so "../CSS/style.css"

and products.php includes index.php using include "../index.php"
but the css isn't being included because NOW index.php is in the same folder as products.php so relative path won't work !! 
is there any solution a part from absolute path because i don't want people to know the structure of my project 
if there is not can you give me the absolute path or can i somehow hide the absolute path from the user

thank you in advance for your time

Comment: How would absolute paths reveal something of your structure that can't be deduced from relatives? Or what does the structure even matter?

Comment: Apart from this: using relative paths carries nearly the same information, apart from the absolute base path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/style.css">
```